# Match columns against the row

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have two files which are tab limited format and both are in different format like this

File1

```
Cat1 Dog2 Cat2
Ele5 Mou5.2 Chi7
Cat1 Ele5 Cat2
```

File2

```
Animal1 Dog2
Animal1 Cat2
Animal1 Ele5
Animal2 Ele5
Animal2 Cat2
Animal2 Cat1
Animal3 Ele5
Animal3 Chi7
Animal3 Mou5.2
```

And I need to match with each row in file1 with the columns file2, if it not matching leave that string

expected output:

```
Animal3 Ele5 Chi7 Mou5.2
```

Tried with awk using -w -F -f but it is not working for this

Comment: Could you please add sample expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: this is the expected output
Animal3 Ele5 Chi7 Mou5.2

Comment: Please do mention clear logic of how to get this output in your question and let us know then. As it is still not clear, how we should get expected output from this given samples.

Comment: The idea is that to look at the first 3 rows in the first file is matching to the second file with respect to a common string.

Comment: Why is there no `Animal1 Cat1 Cat2 Dog2` in the output? What does it mean to `grep with each column in file1 with the file2`?

Comment: I need to look at each row in the 1st file is matching to the columns in the second file with respect to the first common columns in the second file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Considering `Animal1 Cat1 Ele5 Cat2` should be there in your output as per your mentioned logic.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$2]
  b[$1]
  next
}
{
  for(j in b){
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      if((j,$i) in a){
        count++
      }
    }
    if(count==NF){
      print j,$0
    }
  }
  count=""
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution as per OP's request:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];b[$1];next}{for(j in b){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if((j,$i) in a){count++}}if(count==NF){print j,$0}}count=""}' file2 file1
```

Comment: @user3295716, it worked fine for me, are you passing `file2  file1` to my awk code right? Also please confirm that you don't have control M characters in your file(s) by doing `cat -v file1` and `cat -v file2` lemme know on both the questions here.

Comment: yeah it is showing error. I did like this awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]b[$1]next}{for(j in b){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if((j,$i) in a){count++}}if(count==NF){print j,$0}}count=""}' file2 file1

Comment: @user3295716, If you are running it in one liner then try `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2];b[$1];next}{for(j in b){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if((j,$i) in a){count++}}if(count==NF){print j,$0}}count=""}' file2 file1` this also worked for me. Have you checked on control M check part, please do lemme know?